# ReactJs frontend & Passport NodeJs backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport-local

I am building a project which is API RESTful with NodeJS, Express & Passport. And for the Frontend of this application I want to use `ReactJS`.

Can I create a separate project with create-app-react for my frontend and fetch my API while keeping the benefits of Passport ? Or I should send always the user's information in my request? Or serve my Frontend on the same server of the API?

Comment: Are you asking if you can have a separate app for your API vs what serves your react app?  Yes of course.

Comment: No, it's more "Can I have a separate app and benefit of the passport-local initialiazed on my API?". And if yes, should I send user data at each request on my API?

Comment: It depends how you're authenticating.  If your using sessions, then you can use redis store and share sessions between two express apps.

Comment: Yes, I am using sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have a client & a server on 2 differents port, and keep the benefits of Passport.

But for that, when you `fetch` you API use `credentials : 'include'`

Because, by default, [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) won't send or receive any cookies from the server, resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the credentials init option must be set).

Example:

```
fetch('https://example.com', {
  credentials: 'include'  
})
.then( res => {
  // Some stuff...
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```